# Openning too many windows to authenticate

Tags: excel, authentication, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I connect to snowflake from Excel using odbc, it opens too many windows to authenticate. To load a simple table, over 20 authentication windows opened till it finally showed the data. I believe it should authenticate only once and not for every small transaction?

Comment: Please provide details of how you are connecting to Snowflake using ODBC. Are you using VBA; are you using Data > Get Data (and, if so, is this for a single dataset in your workbook?

Comment: I'm connecting to Snowflake through Data -> Get Data -> from ODBC. I do this in a new excel file without any other data sources. When I select the ODBC connection (to connect to Snowflake) it opens many windows in Edge to authenticate. After opening all those authentication pages, I will be able to see list of Databases in Snowflake. If I expand a database to see schemas, many new windows will open again.  This is what I see in each window:
Your identity was confirmed and propagated to Snowflake ODBC driver. You can close this window now and go back where you started from.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem but a couple of things you might try: (1) If you are using a User DSN try using a System DSN (2) To rule out it being a browser issue, try setting your default browser to Chrome rather than Edge and see if Chrome generates multiple windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed now. It was due to a setting on Snowflake account to set allow_id_token = true :)

Comment: how did you change this setting?